# How to use only the global planner without the other move_base components?

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-melodic, global-costmap, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working on an autonomous robot. I have implemented my own local planner and controller. I would just like to use the `costmap_2d` and `global_planner` from the ROS navigation stack. How do I launch the global costmap and global planner just like `move_base` would?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/309041/how-to-use-only-the-global-planner-without-the-other-move_base-components?/) by [Subodh Malgonde](https://answers.ros.org/users/36410/subodh-malgonde/) on ROS Answers with karma: 512 on 2018-11-21

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/melodic-devel/global_planner/src/plan_node.cpp

`rosrun global_planner planner`

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2018-11-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1